# How to properly check field uniqueness using custom validator in Grails?

Tags: hibernate, grails, validation

I've got a ClientAttribute domain class, with 2 fields: `name (String)` & `project (Project)`.
There is a one-to-many relation between `Project` and `ClientAttribute` Inside single project, all names have to be unique.

At first I thought about creating following validator:

```
name(blank: false, validator: { val, obj ->
            if (ClientAttribute.findByProjectAndName(obj.project, val)) return ['clientAttribute.name.unique']
        })
```

Unfortunately, when creating new instance of `ClientAttribute` I do it by adding new instance to the `clientAttributes` field on project instance and by saving the project instance. This in turn saves rest of the objects in the set `clientAttributes`. When saving second object in the set, the validator is fired, and it throws me an error, because the `findBy()` method returns the same object.

I'm wondering, what's the proper way to perform such check?
I could modify the query not to return the same object as I am currently saving, but I'm wondering if there's no simpler solution to my problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I don't understand your domain model, but what prevents you from using [Grails Unique Constraint](http://grails.org/doc/2.1.x/ref/Constraints/unique.html) in ClientAttribute on both project and name? Like this:

```
name blank: false, unique: 'project'
```

Comment: I'm not sure why I assumed the field is boolean only. Dammit! Thanks David!